# PHPExcel, записать массив данных в EXCEL документ с изначальными данными. Сохранить начальные и новые значения

Tags: php, массивы, phpexcel

Имеется след. задача:
Есть Веб-интерфейс, на котором выбираются значения для формирования SQL-запроса.
Есть два варианта записи полученных данных. В готовый, пустой документ `excel`. И в подгружаемый пользователем. Тот документ, что подгружает пользователь уже содержит значения в определенных ячейках . Мне необходимо сохранить массив данных из подгруженного документа, затем объединить его с массивом по SQL запросу, и записать  итог в документ.  Или есть простой способ выставить условие, чтобы массив полученных данных не затирал изначальные данные в документе.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
$write_only_these_kpis = $write_only_these_kpis ?? array();
    $write_only_these_kpis = array_map('strtolower', $write_only_these_kpis);
    $filter_enabled = (count($write_only_these_kpis) > 0) ? TRUE : FALSE; 
    $inputFileName = $dummy_file;
    $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
    $numOfSheets = $objPHPExcel->getSheetCount();


    for ($i = 0; $i < $numOfSheets; $i++) {
        $curr_sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet($i);
        $sheet_name = $curr_sheet->getTitle();

        if (!isset($kpi_row_nums[$sheet_name])) {
            //echo "skipping sheet".$sheet_name."\n";
        } else {
            //echo "Handling sheet ".$sheet_name."...\n";
            $kpi_column = (in_array($sheet_name, $regions)) ? "F" : "G";
            $slaCriticalColumn = (in_array($sheet_name, $regions)) ? "C" : "D";
            $slaTargetColumn = (in_array($sheet_name, $regions)) ? "D" : "E";
            $slaBonusColumn = (in_array($sheet_name, $regions)) ? "E" : "F";
            $kpiValueColumn = (in_array($sheet_name, $regions)) ? "F" : "G";

            foreach ($kpi_row_nums[$sheet_name] as $kpi_name => $kpi_row_num) {

                // By default write all KPIs from DB to file
                $write_allowed = TRUE;

                // Check kpi is in kpi filter
                if ($filter_enabled and ! in_array($kpi_name, $write_only_these_kpis)) {
                    $write_allowed = FALSE;
                }

                if (!isset($TA_data[$sheet_name][$kpi_name])) {
                    $kpi_val = "-"; // для колонки "достигнутый уровень"
                    //print_r($TA_data[$sheet_name][$kpi_name]);
                } else {
                    // Round depending on kpi_name
                    $kpi_val = $TA_data[$sheet_name][$kpi_name];
                    switch ($kpi_name) {
                        case 'kmob2' : $kpi_val = round($kpi_val, 4);
                            break;
                        case 'kmob30': $kpi_val = round($kpi_val, 3);
                            break;
                        case 'kmob19': $kpi_val = round($kpi_val, 4);
                            break;
                        case 'kmob18': $kpi_val = round($kpi_val, 4);
                            break;
                        case 'ktf14' : $kpi_val = round($kpi_val, 4);
                            break;
                        case 'ktf20' : $kpi_val = round($kpi_val, 4);
                            break;
                        case 'kmob23': $kpi_val = round($kpi_val, 4);
                            break;
                        case 'kmob21': $kpi_val = round($kpi_val, 4);
                            break;
                        case 'ktf17' : $kpi_val = round($kpi_val, 4);
                            break;
                        default : $kpi_val = round($kpi_val, 2);
                            break;
                    }
                    // Override kpi value with dash if needed
                    if (in_array($kpi_name, $fill_as_dash)) {
                        $kpi_val = "";
                    }
                }

                // Cant replace non-empty value with empty ("-") value
//                        if($kpi_val_not_empty[$sheet_name][$kpi_name] === TRUE AND $kpi_val === "-") {
//                            $write_allowed = FALSE;
//                            echo "CAN'T ERASE NON-EMPTY VALUE ".$kpi_name." = ".$kpi_old_val[$sheet_name][$kpi_name]."\n";
//                        }
                // Write data to file
                if ($write_allowed) {
//                            $kpi_val="-";
                    $prefix = "+";
                    if ($kpi_old_val[$sheet_name][$kpi_name] === $kpi_val) {
                        $prefix = "=";
                    }
                    //echo $prefix." Write  ".$sheet_name."  ".$kpi_name."  ".$kpi_val."\n";

                    $c = $slaCritical[$sheet_name][$kpi_name] ?? '-';
                    $t = $slaTarget[$sheet_name][$kpi_name] ?? '-';
                    $b = $slaBonus[$sheet_name][$kpi_name] ?? '-';

                    $curr_sheet->SetCellValue($kpi_column . $kpi_row_num, $kpi_val);
                    $curr_sheet->SetCellValue($slaCriticalColumn . $kpi_row_num, $c);
                    $curr_sheet->SetCellValue($slaTargetColumn . $kpi_row_num, $t);
                    $curr_sheet->SetCellValue($slaBonusColumn . $kpi_row_num, $b);
                }
            }
        }
        $curr_sheet->setSelectedCell('A1');
    }


//    $date_today = date("m.d.y");
//    $xls_name = $date_today.'_techact.xlsx';
//    
//    ob_end_clean();
//    header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
//    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="techact.xlsx"');
//    //header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
//     $objWriter->save('php://output');



    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, $inputFileType);
    $objWriter->save($ready_file);
```

Comment: Код лучше привести в виде текста

Comment: То есть имеется 2 массива. один от скана документа, второй от запроса к базе. итогово в документ пишется массив из базы. Как при непустом значении, не писать данные из базы??